# Angular HttpInterceptor: How to use RxJS for multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

Here is `AuthInterceptor`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const Token = this.authService.getToken();

        if (!Token) {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
 
        // Refresh Token first
        if (Token.expiresRefreshToken && Number(Token.expiresRefreshToken) < Date.now()) {
            this.authService.refreshTokenRefresh(Token.tokenref)
            .subscribe((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('tokenref', response.tokenref);
                localStorage.setItem('tokenrefexp', response.tokenrefexp);
            });
        }
        // Then next Access Token
        if (Token.expiresToken && Number(Token.expiresToken) < Date.now()) {
            this.authService.refreshToken(Token.tokenref)
            .subscribe((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
                localStorage.setItem('tokenexp', response.tokenexp);
            });
        }
        // Original request with updated custom headers
        return next.handle(req.clone({
            headers: req.headers
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
            .set('X-Auth-Provider', localStorage.getItem('provider'))
        }));
    }

}
```

I need to evaluate those conditions before sending the request because some custom headers may change after methods `refreshToken` and `refreshTokenRefresh`. Is there a way to evaluate everything inside a RxJS operator? First condition (`refreshTokenRefresh`), then second (`refreshToken`) and finally the `req`.

Update: I'm getting this error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` How to fix this?

Comment: Just put the last part of the code in `else` and put `next.handle` inside your `if`s.

Comment: You might want to read [RxJS, where is the If-Else Operator?](https://blog.rangle.io/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to wait until some requests will be completed (evaluate order does not matter?) than do another request.

`const queue = this.handleRefreshToke(this.handleRefreshTokenRefresh([]));` - place there all request that should be done before we call `next.handle`.
Use the `forkJoin` to wait until all request (placed in queue) will be completed than map to another Obervable ( `mergeMap` ).

PS We could also move `handleRefreshTokenRefresh` and `handleRefreshToke` to separated HttpInterceptor.

**EDITED** To prevent recursive call of interceptors we should [skip interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46469349/5801495) for refreshTokens call.

```
export const InterceptorSkipHeader = 'X-Skip-Interceptor';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

    handleRefreshTokenRefresh(queue: Observable<void>[]) {
        const Token = this.authService.getToken();
        if (Token.expiresRefreshToken && 
            const req = this.authService.refreshTokenRefresh(Token.tokenref)
              .pipe(tap((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('tokenref', response.tokenref);
                localStorage.setItem('tokenrefexp', response.tokenrefexp);
            }));
            return [...queue, req];
        }
        return queue;
    }

    handleRefreshToke(queue: Observable<void>[]) {
        const Token = this.authService.getToken();
        if (Token.expiresToken && Number(Token.expiresToken) < Date.now()) {
            const req = this.authService.refreshToken(Token.tokenref)
              .subscribe((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
                localStorage.setItem('tokenexp', response.tokenexp);
            });
            return [...queue, req];
        }
        return queue;
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       if (req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
            const headers = req.headers.delete(InterceptorSkipHeader);
            return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
        }

        const Token = this.authService.getToken();

        if (!Token) {
            return next.handle(req);
        }

        const queue = this.handleRefreshToke(this.handleRefreshTokenRefresh([]));

        return forkJoin(queue).pipe(
            mergeMap(()=>{
                return next.handle(req.clone({
                    headers: req.headers
                        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'))
                        .set('X-Auth-Provider', localStorage.getItem('provider')),
                }));
            })
        );
    }

}
```

Add `InterceptorSkipHeader` to refreshTokens to skip interceptors.

```
// AuthService

refreshTokenRefresh(token){
   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '');
   return this.httpClient
    .get(someUrl, { headers })
}

refreshToken(token){
   const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '');
   return this.httpClient
    .get(someUrl, { headers })
}
```

Comment: evaluate order does matter because i need a valid refresh token (first condition) to generate an access token (second condition).

Comment: You can use `concat` instead of `forkJoin`

Comment: can you validate my answer? i think there may be something wrong because my server is a little unstable: restarts many times when using interceptor. I'm getting this error on console `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: You need to skip [interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46469349/5801495) for `handleRefreshToken ` and `handleRefreshTokenRefresh `.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to stop calling interceptor with `HttpBackEnd` before but it didn't worked.