# Console error as Endpoint unreachable and application fails to load

Tags: angular, typescript

I have upgraded Angular 5 to 7 and kept **rxjs-compat**.  Application was working fine in this case, but later we removed **rxjs-compat** and done respective changes. And we are getting error while loading
the application as "**Enpoint unreachable**" while bootstrapping the application. 
We are using

```
"@ngx-config/core": "7.0.0",
"@ngx-config/http-loader": "7.0.0",
```

I suspect this package is creating some issue after upgrade.But compilation is success, only while running the application it shows console error as endpoint unreachable.
    Any body else faced this issues or any idea how to debugg these kind of issues.

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT

After further analysis I found that, this error is happened because of @ngx-config update, nothing to do with rxjs-compat.

```
// for config loader
export function configFactory(http: HttpClient): ConfigLoader {
  return new ConfigHttpLoader(http, environment.configFile);
}
```

Interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 
//etc
})
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire exception / stack trace?

Comment: Can you share the entire error, and some more of your code. I actually had similar problem, if you just  share a link to your repo, I'll try and fix it.

Comment: @Lissy Http interceptor and config core are conflicting some how. If I remove http interceptor other one is working fine, either of one is working fine. Same thing is working fine in another application.

Comment: I tried this as well :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910312/angular-6-use-http-interceptor-with-config-service but nothing seems to be worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many approaches mentioned in github and SO, nothing workout for me. Final thing which I done to make it work is,

Calling config in main .ts before application bootstraps and set in session storage, you can create a class file and do your logic there as well.

```
const url = "configurl"// read from your environment file
const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
          if (xmlHttp.responseText) {
            const config: any = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            if (config) {
             window.sessionStorage.setItem("config", JSON.stringify(config));

            }
        }
      };
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
```

**Appmodule**

```
export function configFactory(http: HttpClient): ConfigLoader {
  return new ConfigStaticLoader(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("config")));
}
```

And this works fine for me.

Original issue was , I am not able to use config loader and http interceptor together.