# Angular post-request with a multipart form has wrong content type

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular-httpclient

I'm using the following function to upload a file to a server with the HttpClient of angular 7

```
  pushFileToStorage(productId, key, file: File): Observable<any> {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();

    formdata.append('prod', file);
    let url_ = '/admin5/api/v1/product/images/upload?';
    url_ += "productId=" + encodeURIComponent("" + productId) + "&";
    url_ += "kind=" + encodeURIComponent("" + key);

    return this.http.post(url_,formdata);
  }
```

The problem I'm having is that the HttpClient sets the wrong content type header (application/json instead of "multipart/form-data") and so the server can't read the file.
This is what I see on the developer tools

[image]

[image]

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just found out that the project I'm working on has an HttpInterceptor that is adding a content-type "application/json" by default to any request that doesn't set the content type. So that was the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly was what happening.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Three hours I just spent trying to figure out why files wouldn't upload, three hours I'll never get back and it's because I'd tried to be clever with a HttpInterceptor and was adding a Content-Type header.

Comment: After 3 hour research I have found that post. And was exactly that problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am using FormData also. The reason behind this was the HTTP interceptor as @Maurizio Pozzobon stated in the accepted answer. I am using HTTP Interceptor like below--

[image]

Here My interceptor send my token to every http call as

> 'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Which was creating the wrong content type error. So I need to bypass the interceptor for this type of call. I follow from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013534/5153538).

I import HttpBackend

[image]

Declare HttpClient variable

[image]

Declare in the Constructor

[image]

Now using this httpclient i request Post api call with formdata carring my file. This Http Post call bypass Http Interceptor. My problem solved this way.

Comment: could you please elaborate further how you solved your problem. I'm facing the same upload issue. ``System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/json``

Answer (score 0):

This is the server header, and the server answers you using json and this is absolutely normal. It’s easier and faster to look for a library to load pictures like this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader
or https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file

Comment: no, that is the request header, the browser is set to italian and "richiesta" means "request"