# Angular 8 can't upload formdata/multi-part to server

Tags: http-post, multipartform-data, angular8

I'm trying to upload a xlsx file to server, but I receive two different errors, whether I specify the contentType in the http request header or not. If I specify "Content-type: multipart/form-data" I get the following error:

> FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart
>   boundary was found

Then, if I do not specify the content type (as proposed in different answers), I get this error:

> current request is not a multipart request

This is what I do to upload the file. HTML (input fired by a button that calls an `uploadFile()` method):

```
<input type="file" #fileUpload id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" accept=".xlsx" style="display:none;" />
```

.ts:

```
uploadFile() {
    const fileUpload = this.fileUpload.nativeElement;
    fileUpload.onchange = () => {
      this.file = fileUpload.files[0];
      this.uploadFileToServer();
    };
    fileUpload.click();
  }


  uploadFileToServer() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.file);
    this.importService.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(d => { 

    });
  }
```

In the service the method does this:

```
this.http.post(
        apiUrl,
        formData,
        options
      );
```

where in options there are the specified headers:

```
let applicationHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 applicationHeaders = applicationHeaders.append('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

multipart or blank.

In the POST request in the request payload I have:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarytNckytdr7I8wQcuc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Template (2).xlsx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarytNckytdr7I8wQcuc--
```

Comment: Please check this:https://therichpost.com/how-to-upload-image-with-laravel-angular/

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015254/angular-post-request-with-a-multipart-form-has-wrong-content-type?newreg=cf693afa7bac495695b7f6fc72740c10

Comment: I am facing the same issue.