# FormData in angular is not being received from the API end

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to send a JSON object as FormData.
After converting it to FormData using the `convertJsonToFormData` function I am sending it using the service function but the API throws error saying IDs are missing.
As you can observe I am sending the `TrainingProviderId` and hence should be able to post.
Please check and if there's anything else needed I will provide more details.

```js
// In component 

      async addQuestion(position, status) {
    const questionDetails = {
      groupId: this.myForm.value.quesType === 3 ? this.myForm.value.groupId : null,
      isOMR: this.myForm.value.quesType === 1 ? 1 : 0,
      complexity: this.myForm.value.complexity,
      questionType: this.myForm.value.quesType,
      questionDescription: this.myForm.value.question.trim(),
      questionHint: this.myForm.value.questionHint.trim(),
      option1: this.myForm.value.optionA.trim() || this.optionAImg.file,
      option2: this.myForm.value.optionB.trim() || this.optionBImg.file,
      option3: this.myForm.value.optionC.trim() || this.optionCImg.file,
      option4: this.myForm.value.optionD.trim() || this.optionDImg.file,
      answer: this.myForm.value.answer,
      answerFormat: null,
      descriptiveAnswer: this.myForm.value.answerDescription.trim(),
      questionFilePath: '',
      option1FilePath: '',
      option2FilePath: '',
      option3FilePath: '',
      option4FilePath: '',
      answerFilePath: '',
      descriptiveAnswerExplanation: null,
      examOrCourseId: null,
      SectionId: this.myForm.value.section,
      SubsectionId: this.myForm.value.subSection,
      trainingProviderId: this.trainingProviderId,
    };
    if (this.myForm.value.quesType !== 1) {
      questionDetails.questionFilePath = '';
      questionDetails.option1FilePath = '';
      questionDetails.option2FilePath = '';
      questionDetails.option3FilePath = '';
      questionDetails.option4FilePath = '';
      questionDetails.answerFilePath = '';
      questionDetails.option1 = '';
      questionDetails.option2 = '';
      questionDetails.option3 = '';
      questionDetails.option4 = '';
    }
    if (this.myForm.value.quesType === 3) {
      questionDetails.descriptiveAnswer = '';
      questionDetails.answer = '';
    }
    const formData = this.convertJsonToFormData(questionDetails);

    this.questionBankService.createQuestion(formData, this.trainingProviderId).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        if (res.status === 'Success') {
          this.toastr.success(this.translate.instant('question_bank.success.create_question'),
            this.translate.instant('question_bank.success.title'));
          this.router.navigate(['/pages/training-provider/question-bank']);
        } else {
          // this.router.navigate(['401']);
          const index = 1;
          this.toastr.show('Error', `Toast ${index}`, { position, status });
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          this.toastr.danger(this.translate.instant('question_bank.errors.create_question'),
            this.translate.instant('question_bank.errors.create_question_title'));
        }
      },
    );
  }
  convertJsonToFormData(jsonData): FormData {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (const key in jsonData) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(jsonData, key)) {
        const value = jsonData[key];

        if (value instanceof File) {
          formData.append(key, value, value.name);
        } else {
          formData.append(key, value);
        }
      }
    }
    return formData;
  }
// In service
createQuestion(form: FormData, trainingProviderId: string) {
    const userObject = this.authService.getUser();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${userObject.token}`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    const options = { headers };
    const API_URL = `htttps://server_address/api/company/${trainingProviderId}/question`;
    return this.httpClient.post<unknown>(API_URL, form, options).pipe(
      map((data: {status: string}) => data),
      catchError((error) => throwError(() => error)),
    );
  }
```

Comment: maybe a case problem ? Is it `TrainingProviderId` or `trainingProviderId` ?

Comment: Tried changing that it's still not working.

Comment: Try and remove the `Content-Type` header, axios should be able to set that itself. It needs to contain the `boundary` used inside the multipart request body, and when you specify it like this, there is a chance that overwrites the proper one axios would create on its own.

Comment: I tried removing but it's taking application/json by default. And then the data shown is like FormData {} @CBroe

Comment: you have to have multipart parser on the server. also, include server side code and preferably add corresponding tag

Comment: Check if this is the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015254/angular-post-request-with-a-multipart-form-has-wrong-content-type

Comment: @traynor It is added. I can't show you that request but it's quite a normal one. I don't have access to DB as I am working on the Frontend for this. Please consider a simple one as the API is working.

Comment: @SANYAMCHAURASIA well, the message you get indicates that server might not be able to process multipart request.. but without server side code, it's impossible to say..

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems like you have a typo in your API_URL. You have written htttps instead of https. Please correct it to ensure that the API URL is formed correctly.
2. Additionally, make sure that the Content-Type header is set correctly in your request. In your code, you are trying to set headers using headers.append(), but HttpHeaders are immutable, and append() returns a new instance. So, you should set headers like this:

> const headers = new HttpHeaders()
> .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userObject.token}`)
> .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
> .set('Accept', 'application/json');

This way, the Content-Type header will be set correctly to multipart/form-data.
Make these changes and try again.It should work fine