# ng-http-loader not working for API calls handled via httpbackend

Tags: angular, loader, httpbackend

I was trying to create a service so that all API calls in that service will not be appended with token. I achieved this using HttpBackend. But now the ng-http-loader is not working for these API's.

### What I Require

ng-http-loader to work in API calls handled through HttpBackend.

### home-http.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeHttpService {
  private http: HttpClient;
  constructor(handler: HttpBackend) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(handler);
  }
```

### app.module.ts

```js
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        TooltipModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgbModule,
        AuthModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        NgHttpLoaderModule.forRoot()
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorsHandler },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

### app.component.html

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 <ng-http-loader [backdrop]="true" [debounceDelay]="100" [extraDuration]="300" [minDuration]="300" [opacity]="0.6" [backgroundColor]="'#767676'" [spinner]="spinkit"></ng-http-loader>
```

### api.service.ts

```
import { HomeHttpService } from '../home-http.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class APIService {
  constructor(private apiservice: HomeHttpService) {}
```

The ng-http-loader is working in api calls from all other services except the api.service.ts

Comment: In `api.service.ts` i dont see setting of `handler`?

Comment: handler is set in home-http.service. api.service are where the API calls are written using the home-http.service

Comment: Can you provide the stackblitz?

Comment: I'll try. Havent used StackBlitz before

Comment: Minimal represention will be very helpful.

Comment: I have to setup everything right to do a http call

Comment: try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acanyj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204947/discussion-between-avinash-and-plochie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this, here are the key points.

When you provide `HttpBackend` in `HttpClient`, it will ignore the all the interceptors, and hence `ng-http-loader` will not work, as it is unaware of the request.

Now this can be overcome by using header with the request as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469349/how-to-make-an-angular-module-to-ignore-http-interceptor-added-in-a-core-module/49047764).

**Interceptor**

```js
export const InterceptorSkipHeader = 'X-Skip-Interceptor';

@Injectable()
export class SkippableInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
      const headers = req.headers.delete(InterceptorSkipHeader);
      return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
    }
    ...  // intercept
  }
}
```

Now, from service, for the API you wish not to have interceptor, you can set this header.

```js
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '');
this.httpClient.get(someUrl, { headers })
    ...
```