# Posting multipart form data angular

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing an angular app where, I have implemented an interceptor which adds token and content-type 'application/json' to the requests. Now there are are some apis where I need to post multipart data and hence content-type application/json wont be applicable there. How can I handle this scenario, as application/json is getting appended to all requests, hence overriding content type for multipart data api requests.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469349/how-to-make-an-angular-module-to-ignore-http-interceptor-added-in-a-core-module/49047764

Comment: You can manually set `content-type` header to `multi-part/formdata` on those API calls, and then at your interceptor, set `content-type: application/json` for the request only if it has not been set already.

Comment: @Mridul thanks for the link. Really liked the approach.

Comment: @ar-m-an I had already used this approach but it was not suitable for some scenarios