# APP_INITIALIZER doesn't return

Tags: angular

I want to load app settings before the Angular application starts.
I copied in the code from another project but it stopped working.
What is wrong?

In `app.module.ts`:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    multi: true,
    deps: [AppSettingsService],
    useFactory: (appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) => {
      return () => {
        return appSettingsService.init();
      };
    }
  },
]
```

And here is the `app-settings.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppSettingsService {

  private appsettings: Appsettings;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  init(): Promise<Appsettings> {
    console.warn('AppSettingsService.init'); // This appears in the console.
    return this.http.get<Appsettings>('appsettings.json').pipe(
      tap(response => {
        console.warn('AppSettingsService.init.tap'); // This does not appear in the console.
        this.appsettings = response;
      })
    ).toPromise();
  }

  get authority(): string {
    return this.appsettings.jwtBearerSettings.authority;
  }
}

class Appsettings {
  baseUri: string;
  angularClientApiURI: string;
  jwtBearerSettings: JwtBearerSettings;
}

class JwtBearerSettings {
  authority: string;
}
```

In the project from which this is copied I see in the browser tools a `GET` request for `appsettings.json` but not so in the project to which it has been copied.

**Update**

I have found that if I remove the `AuthInterceptor` from the `porviders` then it starts working.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(request));
  }

  addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<unknown>): HttpRequest<unknown> {
    const token = this.authService.access_token; // (The id_token also works but can be much larger because it contains more claims.)
    if (token) {
      const tokenReq: HttpRequest<any> = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      return tokenReq;
    }
    else {
      return request;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `APP_INITIALIZER` is using `HttpClient` which depends on `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` which thus creates a mutual dependency.
*cf.* https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26845

The solution is
[How to make an angular module to ignore http interceptor added in a core module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469349/how-to-make-an-angular-module-to-ignore-http-interceptor-added-in-a-core-module)

which looks like this, i.e., to use `HttpBackend` to construct a `HttpClient` instead of having `HttpClient` provided by the DI which uses the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`.

```
export class AppSettingsService {

  private httpClient: HttpClient;
  private appsettings: Appsettings;

  constructor(private httpBackend: HttpBackend) {
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
  }
```

Comment: Happy it was useful :)